# Standard Deviation Formula Questions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance, standard-deviation

Is there a generalization of the standard deviation formula for sampling from an urn containing two values, $|b - a| * √(\Pr(a) * \Pr(b))$, to one that works for three or more values (i.e., $a$, $b$, and $c$)?  I assume the pattern inside the $√$ would extend via multiplying by $\Pr(c)$, but I'm not sure how the absolute value factor would change since it represents a distance between $a$ and $b$.

Also, how does this formula turn into the "regular" standard deviation formula when an arbitrary number of values is supplied?

Comment: Standard deviation of what?

Comment: @herbsteinberg An urn, for example, from which the values $a$ and $b$ can be sampled.

Comment: Standard deviations are for random variables, not for containers.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Aren't a random variable and container-sampling homomorphic?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Wikipedia states, "The standard deviation of a random variable, statistical population, data set, or probability distribution is the square root of its variance."  Surely a container and a data set are interchangeable?

Comment: I am fully aware of the definition of standard deviation.  If you are unable to define the random variable(s) that you are trying to describe, I give up.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Perhaps this is what you're looking for:  $X\ =\ \begin{cases}a,\ \ \ \text{if a is sampled from the urn} \\ b, \ \ \ \text{if b is sampled from the urn}\end{cases}\ \ \ \text{where }a\text{ and }b\text{ are real numbers}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X)=aP_a+bP_b$, $E(X^2)=a^2P_a+b^2P_b$.  $var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$
$=a^2P_a(1-P_a)+b^2P_b(1-P_b)-2abP_aP_b=P_aP_b(a-b)^2$,

which gives the standard deviation you have.  Note that the absolute value is simply the result of the square root.

To get the formula for $n$ items, use the same approach.  $E(X)=\sum_1^n a_kP_k$ and $E(X^2)=\sum_1^na_k^2P_k$ immediately giving the variance $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Using a similar manipulation, $Var(X)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^nP_jP_k(a_j-a_k)^2$